# Установка компонентов Belle React

Tags: reactjs, npm

Как использовать набор компонентов belle в новых версиях react?
Пытался устанавливать зависимость react-css-property-operations, но не помогло

Comment: https://github.com/nikgraf/belle/issues/350#issuecomment-682006700